# Как вывести ошибку с позицией в регулярных выражениях

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, re

я провожу синтаксический анализ переменных python на языке python с помощью регулярных выражений. Для того чтобы вывести синтаксическую ошибку я  могу найти строку, но не могу найти позицию в строке, подскажите пожалуйста каким образом это реализовать?
Пример регулярного выражения для присвоения переменной целого числа

```
import re
pattern = r"^(\s)*([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*)\s*=\s*([1-9]\d*)\s*$"
string = "a = s2"
```

Нужно найти позицию ошибки в строке, а именно букву "s".

Comment: добавьте минимально воспроизводимый пример в ваш вопрос 
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: не думаю, что `re` предоставляет такую возможность.

Answer (score 2):

[Метод `re.search()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) в библиотеке `re`. Пример:

```py
import re
pattern = r"a"
string = "nndfuøkdiaunsdk"
result = re.search(pattern, string)
```

Если посмотреть в `result`, то там лежит это:

```py
>>> result
<re.Match object; span=(9, 10), match='a'>
```

Объект который хранит положение в строке (`span`) и какое совпадение. Отсчет с нуля, конечное значение не включается. Т. е. запись (9,10) буквально значит на 9 позиции с нуля

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но в моем примере
`import re
pattern = r"^(\s)*([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*)\s*=\s*([1-9]\d*)\s*$"
string = "a = s2"
result = re.search(pattern, string)
print(result)`
где реализовано регулярное выражение для присвоение переменной целого числа result выводит None, то есть он находит лишь совпадение, но не найдет позицию ошибки в string

Comment: @BeckerWesley да, ок, минимально воспроизводимый пример нужен был